# How to restrict object creation

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider following example

```
class Key:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

d = {}

for x in range(1, 10000):
    t = Key(x)
    d[t] = x
```

This will create 10000 keys. Is it possible to control the object creation of class key, for example we cannot create more than 5 objects of key class. The loop should not be changed in any ways.

Comment: This will create 9999 keys actually.

Comment: Why do you want to limit the number of objects?

Answer (score 7):

You can control how, or how many objects are created by giving your class a [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

```
class Key(object):
    _count = 0

    def __new__(cls, s):
        if cls._count == 5:
            raise TypeError('Too many keys created')

        cls._count += 1
        return super(Key, cls).__new__(cls, s)

    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
```

`Key.__new__()` is called to create a new instance; here I keep a count of how many are created, and if there are too many, an exception is raised. You could also keep a pool of instances in a dictionary, or control creating of new instance in other ways.

Note that this only works for [*new-style classes*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), inheriting from `object`.

Comment: Aren't some concurrency-related precautions needed?

Comment: @bereal: this code is not thread safe, no. That's not the point here, the point is to illustrate how you can hook into instance creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a metaclass approach

```
import weakref
import random

class FiveElementType(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, d):
        super(FiveElementType, self).__init__(name, bases, d)
        self.__cache = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def __call__(self, *args):
       if len(self.__cache) == 5:
           return random.choice(self.__cache.values())
       else:
           obj = super(FiveElementType, self).__call__(*args)
           self.__cache[len(self.__cache)] = obj
           return obj

class Key(object):
    __metaclass__ = FiveElementType
    def __init__(self, s):
       self.s = s
```

You can choose a random element or select it on the base of stored index. In this approach your loop don't fail with an exception that can be right or not, depending on your intention.